# Passing pointer in argument of a function

Tags: c++, sorting

This is a code of  merge function(just merge not merge sort) can you please tell me why *a (pointer) has been used in argument of function and if I don't use it, it gives error ??

```
void merge(int *a,int s,int e){
    int mid = (s+e)/2;

    int i = s;
    int j = mid+1;
    int k = s;

    int temp[1000];

    while(i<=mid && j<=e){
        if(a[i] < a[j]){
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else{
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i<=mid){
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while(j<=e){
        temp[k++]  = a[j++];
    }

    //We need to copy all element to original arrays
    for(int i=s;i<=e;i++){
        a[i] = temp[i];
    }


}
```

Comment: It gives you an error if you don't use the function or if you don't use the pointer? The author used a pointer because the function expects an array and this is the way to pass an array to a function. An array decays to a pointer. An alternative would be a reference to `std::array`

Comment: What are you trying to use instead of a pointer? I mean this code `a[i]` when used in a function means that `a` has to be a pointer. What else could it be? (Or it could be a class type that overloads operator[], but I think that's a bit advanced for the OP).

Comment: if you dont use it as a pointer its indicates its an integer not an array. thus you can not access it with member access operators '[ ]'. in c++ you can use std::array instead of doing things like this.

Comment: If I  only write int a instead of int *a and call function  merge(a,s,e); where a is array s and e are numeric values then it gives error but works fine with int *a argument .

Comment: You can't pass an array to a function if a single element is expected. But you can pass an array to a function that expects a pointer because an array decays to a pointer to the first element

Comment: @AYUSHAZAD So what makes you think it's OK to write `int a` and then try and pass an array? ints and arrays are not compatible. How would that work? An int is a single value, and array is multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

a points to an **array** of int not to a single one. If you try to use `int a` instead of `int* a` you are just passing a single integer by value.

Comment: seeing only the function definition all we know for sure is that `a` does point to a single `int`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 but seeing its implentation where a[i] is acessed in a loop we know for sure it is not a single int. Of course the array could have the length of 1 and the code would still work. But the function is written to process any number of int not just a single one.

Comment: I  forgot to use int a[] ,as it has been very long since I revised function ,Thank you..

Comment: I would change the wording of the first senctence, because `a` does point to a single `int` (yes it does make a difference if that single `int` is just a single `int` or the first element of an array, but nevertheless `a` does point to a single `int`)

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, if you don't use a pointer then it becomes an integer but you are expecting an array.

You can use '[ ]' also like this:

```
void merge(int a[],int s,int e)
```